# Use C library in Android over NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

**What I want to do:**

I've found a [C library which computes an audio stream's pitch](http://www.schmittmachine.com/dywapitchtrack.html) and want to use it in Android.

I thought instead of porting it I could also use it with the help of the NDK, right?

How does this work? I have to install the NDK, of course, and then? Can I call functions of this C library just as normal in Android?

**The library in C that I want to "import":**

```
#include "second_c_file.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef max
#define max(x, y) ((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y)
#endif
#ifndef min
#define min(x, y) ((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y)
#endif

int _power2p(int value) {
    ...
}

typedef struct _minmax {
    int index;
    struct _minmax *next;
} minmax;

double _test_calculate(double * var1, int var2, int var3) {
    ...
}
```

The file "second_c_file.h" is another file that I need to import, obviously.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good tutorial for how to start working with the NDK can be [found here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/). And yes, you should be able to get it to compile and call it from the NDK without many changes (assuming the code doesn't reference other libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the link to this tutorial! The installation works fine. But when it comes to the integration of the C library into the Android project (the actual use), it doesn't work. My Android application just shows an error message that it had been stopped unexpectedly. I don't know what I did wrong. I did what the tutorial said. And maybe you could have a look at my C library in the question: What changes do I have to do? (... as the C class names must be something like "Java_com_your_package_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction" and in my C library there aren't any classes yet ...).

Comment: Thank you, the tutorial you linked to helped me to install and use the NDK.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the NDK getting started samples here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples

Then in your NDK, look at the `two-libs` example. You will probably want to just statically link your third-party audio pitch detection library to your own C code.

You'll need to look at the Android.mk and modify it to build your third-party library statically and then indicate that your main project uses that library.

It should be pretty straightforward. The NDK (haven't used it in a while) is a bit of a bear. So make sure your build environment (especially if you are using Windows + Cygwin) works. Make sure the hello-jni builds, and the default two-libs builds. Modify the second one and you should be there.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot by referencing the NDK sample "two-libs". But unfortunately, I can only choose one answer.