# How to open .dwg file in Android

Tags: android, cad

I want to open a `.dwg` file in my own Android app.
Is there anyone who knows any good development tool that can help me.
I am trying to find it but just getting nothing related to it. I think very few people use it.
Also, I want to know, how these apps work to open `cad files` which would be developed.

Comment: Don't mix too many large questions. Open dwg files is probably hard enough as it is. Your last sentence, in addition to being unclear, seems a completely different question to me.

Comment: sorry, i thought that .dwg is the only format in autocad.And i just want to open .dwg in my own android app.i know its hard to open it by myself ,so i want to ask if there any good sdk that can be useful to me.

Comment: the "only format" part is not the issue. But *reading*  from a complicated file format and be able to extract information is quite different IMHO from rendering this information into a practical UX / program on a specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem  here is that `.dwg` files have a lot of different versions, and more importantly this format is proprietary, apparently not well documented or not documented at all. And of course, it's not simple data that we are talking about, so good luck for reverse engineering the format yourself.

A look at the [wikipedia page for .dwg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dwg) seem to give some interesting information for your project :

There is already some open source reader developed for this file format, namely  [LibDWG - free access to DWG](http://libdwg.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)

> (...)
>
> This is a library to allow reading data from a DWG file. That's a very
>   important acquisiton, which may improve a lot the ability of the free
>   software comunity to develop more features in the field of computer
>   technical drawing (CAD).
>
> The DWG structure is very complicated, it seems to be crafted so that
>   none can easily understand it. That's a strong reason to not use it,
>   and that's also why we do not provide the writing feature in the
>   library. One should use LibDWG mainly to read such files, filtering
>   them to some other format, free and usable.
>
> (...)

I think this is the developpment tool you wanted.

Comment: thanks.i read the web and i find it is based on C,and i need to be used in android or java,so maybe its not so helpful to me.

Comment: @Airy I edited a bit my question : LibDWG is not a viewer but a DWG *reader* . The programming language difference should not have a strong impact. You can create a Java program that uses a compiled C library. And in any case, some of the algorithm could be reused. In any case, it looks much better to me than starting down from scratch .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920066/how-to-use-c-cpp-library-functions-in-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390811/use-c-library-in-android-over-ndk